# How to get dates along with the functions I perform?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

My initial data frame is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'serialNo':['aaaa','aaaa','cccc','ffff'],
               'Date':['2018-09-15','2018-09-16','2018-09-15','2018-09-19'],
               'moduleLocation':   ['face','head','stomach','legs'],
               'moduleName':   ['singing', 'dance','booze', 'vocals'],
               'warning': [4402, 3747 ,5555,8754],
               'failed':[0,3462,5161,3262]})
```

I have performed the following functions to clean up the data the first is to make all the datatypes as string:

```
all_columns = list(df)
df[all_columns] = df[all_columns].astype(str)
```

This is followed by the function to perform certain concatenations:

```
def concatenate(diagnostics, field, target):
    diagnostics.sort_values(by=['serialNo',field],inplace=True)
    diagnostics.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    diagnostics[target] = \
    diagnostics.groupby(['serialNo'], as_index=False)[field].transform(lambda s: ','.join(filter(None, s)))
    diagnostics.drop([field],axis=1,inplace=True)
    diagnostics.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    return diagnostics

module = concatenate(df[['serialNo','moduleName']], 'moduleName', 'Module')
Warn = concatenate(df[['serialNo','warning']], 'warning', 'Warn')
Err = concatenate(df[['serialNo','failed']], 'failed', 'Err')
Location = concatenate(df[['serialNo','moduleLocation']], 'moduleLocation', 'Location')

diag_final = pd.merge(module,Warn,on=['serialNo'],how='inner')
diag_final = pd.merge(diag_final,Err,on=['serialNo'],how='inner')
diag_final = pd.merge(diag_final,Location,on=['serialNo'],how='inner')
```

Now the problem is the Date column no longer exists in my diag_final data frame and I would like to have it. I do not want to make changes to the existing function but just make sure that I have the corresponding Dates. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are likely to be multiple values for each serial number. Hence, you will have to concatenate the values, similar what you are doing for moduleLocation, and moduleName.

```
dates = concatenate(df[['serialNo','Date']], 'Date', 'Date_cat')
diag_final = pd.merge(diag_final,dates,on=['serialNo'],how='inner')
```

Comment: :This give the dates as concatenated strings which somehow doesn't split when I try to spilt it into two separate columns using: result['Date_cat1'] = result.Date_cat.str.split(",") or something like from collections import OrderedDict
diag_final['Date_cat1'] = diag_final.Date_cat.str.split(",")\
                         .apply(lambda x:OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys()).str.join(",")

Comment: Sorry, i am unable to understand this piece of code.